# Ruby on Rails e Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Tenho o seguinte no controller em Ruby on Rails:

```
  def index
    @categorias = Categoria.find(:all)
  end
```

Em minha View tenho o seguinte código para obter as categorias:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var teste = <%= @categorias %>;
    alert(teste.length);
</script>
```

Neste caso nada é retornado. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var teste = <%= raw @categorias.to_json %>;
    alert(teste.length);
</script>
```

Comment: Brilha muito! Muito obrigado fera! Pena que não tem como dar medalha por aqui...